# Как распечатать содержимое jsonify?

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = {
         'name':'name',
         'age':18,
         'stroka':'stroka'
            }
    res = jsonify(data)
    print(res) # пишет Response 111 bytes [200 OK]
```

Могу ли я посмотреть что находится в res и как сформировался json? Следом же вопрос, json как я понял сортирует ключи, как добиться того, чтобы этого не происходило и формировалось так как изначально у меня в словаре?

Comment: 1) Попробуйте напечатать `res.json() или `res.text` или `res.content`. 2) Порядок следования ключей словаря в общем случае не гарантирован. Зачем вам его сохранять? Доступ в словарь происходит не по порядку следования аргументов, а по ключам.

Comment: Ну да, сохранять не надо, а распечатать можно как-то обратно его? То что вы написали не распечатало его, может что-то не так делаю.

Comment: А что у вас напечаталось? В `res` у вас обычный объект `Response`.

Comment: Кстати, в документации дан другой несколько пример: `jsonify(username=g.user.username, email=g.user.email, id=g.user.id)` А, ну там написано, что это одно и то же как у вас сделано.

Comment: Распечаталось `res.json` без скобок, если печатать со скобками пишет 'dict' object is not callable, как скобки в конце влияют на результат?

Comment: А, ну я просто перепутал с `responce` библиотеки `requests`, там такой синтаксис. Ну вы через `res.json` увидели искомое, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, спасибо помогли.